# Trying to load Zen theme in Bitnami Drupal

Tags: drupal, bitnami, zen

I want to use Zen theme in Bitnami Drupal, but when I extract the package in the drupal/htdocs/theme folder, I still don't see the theme listed under Appearances.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put your theme to the sites/all/themes subfolder (relative to Drupal root)  instead of 'theme'.

Comment: thanks, tried that, but it didn't work :) will try downloading zen package zip file instead of gz file

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same problem. I'm using windows 7, drupal 7, xampp, bitnami
I have tried 
-downloading various themes - e.g. Zen, Omega. 
-varying the installation directories. My drupal installation was made using bitnami and did not have a sites/all directory,so I made one and put the theme folders in there. But that didn't work.
-clearing cache many times.

### These themes are just not appearing.

I now have a kind of fix. 
The problem in my case was that bitnami had installed drupal 8, not as I had through drupal 7. Only themes that are explicitly numbered to be compatible with version 8 will show in the list of themes. Go drupal.org -> themes then put in drupal 8 as the core release as a search filter. A small number of themes will come up. I have looked through the ones offered. I found only the ones with a version number of 8.x will appear in my drupal site. For example even though Zen was shown as compatible there was no 8.x version and so I never did get Zen to show. As far as I can tell the options are either to pick a theme where there is an 8.x version - e.g. Mayo - or (and I haven't tried this yet) - uninstall drupal and reinstall without using bitnami to get drupal 7. Ones I have got to appear are - Zurb, fontfolio, AT Core. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not an answer.